# Find the duration between hours

Tags: java, date, time, duration

I want to calculate the duration between hours.

```
SimpleDateFormat defaultFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date hour1 = defaultFormat.parse(time1);
Date hour2 = defaultFormat.parse(time2);
duration = (time2.getTime() - time1.getTime()) / (1000*60); //to minutes
/* hours= duration/60 (hours)  minutes = duration%60 (minutes)
```

Especially the problem occurs when for example hour1 is "22:15" and hour2 is "01:15". The above piece of code save to "duration = 1260" (21 hours).

How can i find the difference between two hours without any bugs?

Comment: Why are you assuming that there is a day difference? / Are these hours within the same day?

Comment: If you always want the smallest possible distance between them (ignoring dates), it would be the smaller of that value and 24-that value.

Comment: Yes it's a day difference. But i want to find how many hours mediate between hour1 and hour2

Answer (score 0):

Mind that you might hit a daylight saving timezone shift date and then difference between 23:00 and 3:00 may be 4, 3 or 5 hours.
I'd suggest you using JodaTime [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) and [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) classes in Java 7 or the [similar API in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) when it comes to manipulate dates and times in Android, or any other Java app. It is much more powerful than the native Java date class.

Here is an example using Joda-Time:

```
DateTime startTime;
DateTime endTime;
Period p = new Period(startTime, endTime);
int hours = p.getHours();
int minutes = p.getMinutes();
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 0):

## Feature, not a bug.

You are inappropriately using a date-time class to represent a time-of-day value. Also, you are using troublesome old [date-time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class for a time-of-day only value, without a date and without a time zone or offset.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( "22:15" ) ;
```

You can do math using the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration d = Duration.of( startLocalTime , stopLocalTime );
```

The catch with using a time-of-day-only value is wrapping around the clock, crossing over midnight. Without the context of dates, how could you expect a proper result? Going from "22:15" to "01:15" did you mean to roll into the next day, the next week, or the next year?

The [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class takes the approach of not crossing midnight. The range of values for `LocalTime` is a total of twenty-four hours, running from the [minimum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIN) of `00:00` to the [maximum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MAX) of `23:59:59.999999999`. So the only way to go from a later time to an earlier time is to travel backwards in time to the earlier point, resulting in a negative number.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse ( "22:15" );
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse ( "01:15" );
Duration d = Duration.between ( start , stop );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "start/stop: " + start + "/" + stop );
System.out.println ( "d.toString(): " + d );
```

> start/stop: 22:15/01:15
>
> d.toString(): PT-21H

That output is standard [ISO 8601 format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

If you want to calculate spans of time between actual moments on the timeline, search for Stack Overflow for `java.time`, `Duration`, `Period`, [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html), `OffsetDateTime`, `Instant`, `Interval`, and “elapsed”. This topic has been covered *many* times already.

As a quick example, let’s assign some arbitrary dates running from January 23rd to 24th of this year in the zone of [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal). Result is three hours of elapsed time. This **result might vary** by date and zone because of anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ZonedDateTime.of( 2017, 1, 23, 22, 15, 0, 0 , z );
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = ZonedDateTime.of( 2017, 1, 24, 01, 15, 0, 0 , z );
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtStop );
```

> zdtStart.toString(): 2017-01-23T22:15-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> zdtStop.toString(): 2017-01-24T01:15-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> d.toString(): PT3H

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/8efWNy).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

### *java.time*

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse("22:15");
        LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse("01:15");

        LocalDateTime startDateTime = today.atTime(startTime);
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = today.atTime(endTime);

        if (startDateTime.isAfter(endDateTime)) {
            endDateTime = endDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIN).plusDays(1).with(endTime);
        }

        Duration duration = Duration.between(startDateTime, endDateTime);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedDuration = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutes() % 60,
                duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedDuration = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT3H
03:00:00
03:00:00
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).